# Grpc server doesn't work after removing the Grpc.Sevrer and started to use services.AddGrpc

Tags: iis, grpc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to remove GRPC.Core library before it's deprecated .
I used Grpc.Server with custom port but now after using service.AddGrpc(), I can't set the port.
My app uses both iis and grpc with net core 3.1.
this is from my launchSettings:

```
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53591",
  "sslPort": 44314
}
```

},

this is the old code:

```
                var grpcServer = new Server
            {
                Services =
                {
                    
                },
                Ports = { new ServerPort(_settings.GrpcServerHost, 50052, ServerCredentials.Insecure) },
                RequestCallTokensPerCompletionQueue = 32768
            };
```

and this is the new code from startup:
//Grpc

```
 services.AddGrpc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            options.MaxReceiveMessageSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB
            options.MaxSendMessageSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MB
        });
```

when I try to run my app I get :

```
Exception=Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I also tried to add the url with UseUrls , in addition to the url for iis but it's not working -

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://*:53591", "http://*:50052")
```

Comment: This is likely due to firewall, you can disable the firewall and try again.